# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQUery UI Position plugin: http://jqueryui.com/position/ to position my icons on a web page. The selectors are grabbed from the database and outputted to JS using PHP in a $myselector variable. This is my current code:

```
var element_selector='<?php echo $myselector;?>';

$('#inline_docxdiv .Featured.Slider').position({
my: "center",
at: "right top",
of: $(element_selector)

});

//append icons,applicable to all

$(divname<?php echo $uniqueid;?>).append('<div id="inline_docxdiv" class="<?php echo $uniqueid;?>"><div id="helpericons_display"><a class="<?php echo $title_toolsetdisplayed;?>" id="questionmarkicon_inlinedoc" title="Display Explanation"><img src="<?php echo $helper_iconpng;?>"></a><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo admin_url().'post.php?post='.$id_toolsetdisplayed.'&action=edit';?>" class="<?php echo $title_toolsetdisplayed;?>" id="sourceicon_inlinedoc" title="View source"><img src="<?php echo $helpersource_iconpng;?>"></a></div></div>');
```

However the icons are not appended correctly and it returns an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

The strange thing is that if I hard-code the selector in the JS code (not outputted by PHP), everything works OK and no error returned in the console. This is the code where I hard-coded the element selector:

```
var element_selector='.idoc-featured-slider';
```

Is there a way to use PHP to output the selector and not encountering the error? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us what's the output of `<?php echo $myselector; ?>`

Comment: You need to make sure that all jquery selectors are string, meaning they all are enclosed between quotation marks. So go ahead and check what's the output for your `$myselector` variable.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into a similar issue.  I was getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

With these dialog position configuration values:

```
position: {my: "center", at: "left top", of: "window"}
```

Per the jQuery [UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position), the value of the "of" property is an object rather than a string. So, when I changed the position values to the following:

```
position: {my: "center", at: "left top", of: window}
```

the error disappeared.

Comment: Your answer was of great help to solve my problem. In my case, my `of` wasn't set to `"window"` but to an `id` of a non-existent element.

Comment: But if you follow the documentation link pointed to - and follow the link with more details, it says the of arg can be a selector (ie a string) or an object.
I can appreciate in the case of 'window' this could be a problem, but I just point out that being a string cannot be the root case because it could be a selector string - http://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to the `of:$()` not working if the object/selector is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your code if any tags is not closed or not. I tried the same and it worked correctly. Apparently , I had an extra  tag

Answer (score 0):

Normally this Kind of error happen while you don't apply Properties of methods like prop() E.g:`$(#"id").prop()`.if you don't specified its properties than also this error occur.

Comment: @msqar according to the docs. **prop()** expects a *propertyName* that is of type *String*
You can find more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName)

Comment: in my case the issue was that the .position(...) code was executed before the properties of the referred elements were calculated by the browser, solution was to put <script> after the element tags

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just changed the following in my  and the error 
*[DataTables warning: table id=bootstrap-data-table2 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4]* 
was gone:

From:

```
                                    [enter image description here][1] <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.HRMS_Tbl_ExpenseClaimModelList)
                                            {

                                                <tr>
                                                    @if (item.Approved == "1")
                                                    {
                                                        <td>@item.Date</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Date</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Type</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Amount</td>
                                                                               }
                                                </tr>

                                            }
                                        </tbody>


                        TO:


                                         <tbody>
                                            @foreach (var item in Model.HRMS_Tbl_ExpenseClaimModelList)
                                            {
                                              if (item.Approved == "1")
                                                    {
                                                <tr>

                                                        <td>@item.Date</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Date</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Type</td>
                                                        <td>@item.Amount</td>

                                                </tr>
                                                    }
                                            }
                                        </tbody>
```